# Trying to set up a virtual network, having issues

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, network-manager, firewall

I'm trying to set up a small virtual network using VirtualBox but having some issues getting each VM to communicate with each other.  Here's my small layout.

1 Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop VM acting as a firewall, with three network interfaces.

- 1 NAT interface
- 1 Interface to connect to a small network that has a workstation also running Ubuntu 18.04 connected to it
- 1 Interface that connects to another small network with a new range of ip's that has a server running the latest version of Turnkey

I want to configure these ip ranges statically, and believe I've updated /etc/network/interfaces correctly, but have attached screenshots.
The firewall VM isn't responding to any pings, and I keep getting an error that says "Activation of network connection failed".

Can anyone help me get my firewall so it will accept pings/join the network? Screenshots of my configurations in Virtualbox and the firewall as well.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9VlT.jpg

Comment: You have a typo in your DMZ connection. Looks like the wrong interface name.

Comment: Ah thank you, I fixed that but I'm still getting the same error unfortunately